# Как сделать сразу мобильное меню bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать сразу мобильное меню, если пунктов слишком много по ширине, чтобы они не выстраивались в два этажа.
Вот картинка: [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

просто хардкод! это если нужно постоянное отображение дропменю

Answer (score 1):

1. Если работать с bootstrap на уровне `less`, то в файле `variables.less` настраивается переменная `@grid-float-breakpoint`.
2. [Customize and download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
   находим эту переменную, задаём значение(например 1280px) меньше которого меню коллапсирует. Скачиваем, пользуемся.

Comment: вот млин откуда это?